# Javascript Time Picker not working inside dynamic table. How to fix this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have dynamic table which add rows on button click. I am using Append function to add rows as much as I want. So the problem is when I want to add javascript Time Picker inside that jquery append. Javascript Time picker not working in dynamic table, but it works outside that table.

This is my Javascript code:

```
$('.timepicker').timepicker();

var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-36251023-1']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'jqueryscript.net']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script');
     ga.type = 'text/javascript';
     ga.async = true;
     ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
     var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();

$(document).ready(function () {
    var i = 1;
    //$('#add').click(function () {
      $(document).on('click', '#add', function() {
        i++;
        $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+ i + '" style="text-align: center;">
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control name_list" name="ime[]"></td>
    <td><select class="form-control" name="operacija[]"><?php $sql = "SELECT nazivSrb FROM operacije ORDER BY nazivSrb ASC";$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?><option value="<?php echo $row['
                    nazivSrb ']; ?>"><?php echo $row['
                    nazivSrb ']; ?></option><?php } ?><option value="Dodatni radovi">Dodatni radovi</option>
            <option value="Nije radio">Nije radio</option>
        </select></td>
    <td style="width: 500px;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6"><input type="text" class="form-control timepicker"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-6"><input type="text" class="form-control timepicker"></div>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control name_list" name="pauza[]"></td>
    <td><select class="form-control" name="status[]">
            <option value="agrikol">Agrikol</option>
            <option value="ostali">Lokalci</option>
        </select></td>
    <td><button type="button" onclick="deleteRow(this)" name="remove" id="'+ i + '" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td>
</tr>');
$('.timepicker').timepicker();
    });


});
```

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same ID on a page.

Comment: And you need to initialize the timepickers you've appended.

Comment: I have changed id to class, but how to initialize timepickers?

Comment: after append, call `$('.timepicker').timepicker()` again.

Comment: Okay, now it works in dynamic table. But I want every field to be unique. This time appears on all fields. See the image. https://pasteboard.co/IBUkPay.png

Comment: `.ckick()` doesn't work for dynamic elements in jQuery. You should use `$(document).on('click', '.bnt', function() {})` as [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9331127/5246900).

Comment: @mr.boris I have changed that too, but it doesn't solve my problem with with fields. Time picker still shows in all fields. I have updated the code.